# looping in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting errors from the two loops below. Is there anything wrong with the syntax? I just started to learn how to use Jupyter Notebook.

[image]

Comment: +) fyi, I was following a lecture video which uses python2, but I'm using python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use python 2 syntax if you are using python 3 compiler.

**Missing parentheses** should give you a clear clue about how you should use print.